# Photoshop Temp Files Become Too Big on Scratch Disk To Save File

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save

I keep on running into a problem where Photoshop temporary files become so large that I don't have enough space on my hard drive to even save the file. The temp files aren't able to be deleted with Photoshop open so until I solve the problem, my only solution is to close the file without saving, losing changes to my work.

Is there a way to limit how much space temp files are allowed to take up on a scratch disk? Do they need to expand to 150GB+ for PS to function?

Until then, another solution is to split smart objects into linked objects so I don't load as much at once - just wondering if this is the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: You do understand that if  you set a limit and subsequently you reach your limit then you can not do what you want anyway. So no setting a limit hardly helps.

Comment: @joojaa You do understand that it's vastly preferable for Photoshop to prevent me from maxing out my disc space with a warning prompt than for me to do work and discover that I can no longer save. So no, your passive aggressive comment hardly helps.

Comment: Its not passive aggressive just checking that you understand the basics before you go into the settings and adjust things. Look into Edit (windows) -> Preferences - Performance. Its in the programs main menu on mac (forgot what its called).

Comment: @joojaa Understandable - I'm no expert which is why I came here. Do you think too much RAM allocation could be causing this or is that unrelated?

Comment: Edit > Purge *might* help. Ideally you would assign scratch space to a separate drive than the operating system.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the recommendation! I'll try Purging next time I run into this issue. I agree that a separate drive is probably the long term solution